# Recursion in C programming Language

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion

I am learning recursion now-a-days. Here are three codes. The first and third is giving me the expected output but the second is not? Can somebody tell me what is just the difference in them.

Code 1:

```
void tail(int i){
if (i>0) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    tail(i-1);
 }
}

int main()
{
    tail(5);
}
```

Code 2:

```
void tail(int i){
if (i>0) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    tail(i--);
 }
}

int main()
{
    tail(5);
}
```

Code 3:

```
void tail(int i){
if (i>0) {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    tail(--i);
 }
}

int main()
{
    tail(5);
}
```

output of Code 1:

5
4
3
2
1

output of Code 2:

5
5
5
.
.
. Infinite

output of Code 3:

5
4
3
2
1

Please help me out. I am confused!

Comment: Oh..it's working for me! For code3.

Comment: The third should work, and it does work when I run it. You might have accidentally included a subtly different program.

Comment: In case 2 you are decrementing i after passing it as a parameter, which is why you keep getting the same number (5).

Comment: Edited. But please explain second code again?

Comment: in the second code , you are doing post decrement, which will only work when that statement is completely executed . But you always remain at tail(5--) , you are never moving to next statement , which chokes you there and printing 5 infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course code number 2 won't. In code number 2 you typed `tail(i--);` what `--` operator (after the variable name) does is first using him in the line you requested and THEN decrease him by one.
Let's say I have the line `printf("%d", i--);` It'll print `i` in it's current value and only after printing it, it will be decreased, it first uses I, and then decreases it - same would happen if you would just type:

```
printf("%d", i);
i--;
```

About the `--` operator BEFORE the variable. It'll first decrease and then do the requested action - so `printf("%d", --i);` will decrease `i` by one and then print it.
We all agree code 1 works well, code 2 actually is in an infinite loop BECAUSE you decrease the variable AFTER calling the function - so it decreases in one function only.
Basically, what it does is like:

```
printf("%d", i); //which is 5
tail(i);//which is still 5
i--; //will never get to this line because we called another function with variable 5
```

and so on.
About code number 3, it works perfectly, it's like code number 1 (but code number one won't actually decrease the variable, just call the function with the variable-1).

EDIT:
for more information, you can search in this [article](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-decrement-operator/) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it :D May God bless you!

Comment: No problem :)
Good luck

Answer (score 5):

1. Result is as expected
2. decrement is post decrement so it would first use current value and then decrement. So function gets repeatedly called with current value so infinite loop.
3. Working fine for me . Similar to first

Comment: @user3742121 Post decrement always uses the value first for main purpose as in here passing as parameter and then decrements it. So first it passes parameter value 5 in first recursion and in that recursion value of i is still 5 before decrementing it and passes 5 to 2nd recusion so on. So decrementing value is not effectively taking place. But if you observe third function - it is pre-decrement so it reduces value and then passes to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it :D May God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

The 3 have to work.  The 2 don't work because i is decremented after been passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with pointers in second case. Each time you are passing the same value into recursive function ... first goes function call and after that you have decrement operation. As a result you have the same value (5) in each recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The second doesn't give you your desired output because you are using post-decrement operator `i--`.

This means "use i and then decrement i" as opposed to `--i` which means "decrement i and then use i".

So in your third case, `i` whose value is 5, gets decremented to 4, and then `tail(4)` is called.
In the second case, `tail(i--)` is called, which means call `tail(5)` and then do `i-=1;` .

If i-- and --i are given as standalone statements, they are equivalent, for example

```
for(int i=5;i>0;i--)
```

is effectively the same as

```
for(int i=5;i>0;--i)
```

But in cases such as follows:

```
int i=5;
int a=i--;
printf("%d %d", i, a);
```

This gives out put 4 5 whereas

```
int i=5;
int a=--i;
printf("%d %d", i, a);
```

will give output 4 4.